# Find $\int (\sin^2 x - 2\cos^2 x)\,dx$

Tags: integration

> Find $$\int (\sin^2 x - 2\cos^2 x)\,dx$$

$$=\frac{1}3 -\cos^3x - \frac{1}4 \sin^3 x$$

This is of course not the right answer which is

$$-\frac{3}4 \sin 2x - \frac{1}2 x + C$$

Comment: Use trigonometric identities like $\cos 2x = 2 \cos^2 x-1$

Comment: @Dagdau Express in terms of $ \cos 2 x $ before integrating.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use $$\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1=1-2\sin^2x$$

and $$\int\cos mx\ dx=\dfrac{\sin mx}m+C$$

Comment: I think I am missing something because I do not see $\cos 2x$ in the original expression, only $2\cos^2 x$

Comment: @dagda1, Replace that with $$1+\cos2x$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

By parts,

$$I=\int\sin^2(x)dx=-\cos(x)\sin(x)+\int\cos^2(x)dx=-\cos(x)\sin(x)+J,$$

and

$$J=\int\cos^2(x)dx=\int(1-\sin^2(x))dx=x-I.$$